# Android layout aligned perfectly in the middle of the parent layout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I am having a trouble implementing a layout as pictured below.

I would like to have a linear or relative layout as bordered black below right in the middle of the parent layout.

The red bordered box will hold the background image of the app.

The black layout will hold the login form.

I have tried various technique to achive this including

```
android:weight with android:width="0dp"
```

I also tried

```
android:scaleType="fitCenter"
```

[image]

Comment: Use relative layout as parent, and apply android:layout_centerInParent="true" to its children you want to float in center.

Comment: Or just use a FrameLayout for that. ```layout_gravity="center"```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/your_background_image_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@android:color/black"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/your_login_container"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true">


        <!-- your login content here -->

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Just replace the default colors background and put whatever image you want.

Answer (score 2):

Use `RelativeLayout` as parent layout and give the child layout this attribute `android:layout_centerInParent="true"`.

And for child layout you have to use wrap_content for width and height.

Answer (score 0):

```
Have you tried something like this:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Login"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Password"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Moreover you wrote that you used

```
android:weight with android:width="0dp"
```

and

```
android:scaleType="fitCenter"
```

Both these are related to the distribution of space for the views rather than their position.